# The process cannot access the file 'x' because it is being used by another process while deleting saved image by application

Tags: vb.net

m a beginner n designing a test application of saving image on hard disk and its name in sql table.
I am able to save, navigate through the records but not able to delete the image.

it gives me error
The process cannot access the file 'x' because it is being used by another process while deleting image

the code is as follows:

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        isProcName = "btnDelete_Click"
        OBJ = New clsImageStoring

```
    Try
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Me, "Do you really want to delete this Record?", "Query", vbYesNo, vbQuestion)
        If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            iiId = DGV.Rows(iiRowno).Cells(0).Value
            iiImageNo = DGV.Rows(iiRowno).Cells(1).Value
            Dim liTempImageNo As Int64 = 0
            If OBJ.Delete(iiId) Then
                Fillgrid()
                liTempImageNo = DGV.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value
                picEmp.Image.Dispose()

                picEmp.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\EmpImages\" & liTempImageNo & ".jpg")
                'File.Delete("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpg")
                FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpg")
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Record Deleted Successfully", "Information", vbOKOnly, vbInformation)
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        clsLog.WriteException(ex, isModuleName, isProcName)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I tried disposing image and from picture box and loading another image in picture box
also m not using any file object for opening the file except the Image class's From file method.

any help will be appreciated
Thankyou

---

dispose didn't work. It is not disposing the image the image was still been used but when I tried to manually delete that particular image I showed me error that the file is been used by " vshost.exe " which is my application itself. So I used File Stream to load picture in image box as been told by James but it still gave me error when I tried deleting any image with following code:

File.Delete("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpg")
File.Delete("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpg")

so I tried this

FileSystem.Kill("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpeg")

and it worked.
thank you james and everyone who gave there precious time for me

Comment: Please show your save logic as it is possible that you left open the file and that's why you get this error.

Comment: not sure why this is tagged with C#.  it's all vb.net code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The picture box probably still hasn't released the image by the time you attempt to delete it from disk, a more reliable approach would be to load the image from a `Stream` e.g.

```
Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream("file path", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
End Using
```

This would prevent any sort of locking on the file.

It does appear to be a [common problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309482).

Comment: Thank you James it works. i have disposed the image but it didn't work so i am using Image class for loading the image in picture box initially and saving the image but for loading the image  in picture box while navigation m using ur part of code.
The only problem was it was giving the same error while deleting

'File.Delete("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpg")
'FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteFile("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpeg")

but it worked with following code

FileSystem.Kill("D:\EmpImages\" & iiImageNo & ".jpeg")

Comment: @user2235765 Clearly the image still has a lock on it somewhere, the code I have posted won't lock the file down so I can only assume you are opening the file elsewhere and not closing it properly.

Comment: I spent like two hours trying to kill processes and nothing worked...came across this and viola...I thought I was taking crazy pills.

Answer (score 6):

This is explained in [the documentation for `Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx):

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

Comment: In fairness, the OP is calling `picEmp.Image.Dispose()` and also clearly states "*I tried disposing image and from picture box*".

Comment: Yep, so clearly the OP understands that the image *has* to be disposed before they can delete it, the issue appears to be *how* the OP can do precisely that - linking them to the documentation to reiterate that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim xx as Image
Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(Fileloc)
xx = Image.FromStream(str)
End Using
picturebox.Image = xx
```